# MYSQL Trigger Update column with same column based on other column

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have the following table.

```
order_id          code             value
   1            sub_total          5.00
   1            shipping           5.00
   1            total              10.00
   2            sub_total          3.00
   2            shipping           6.00
   2            total              9.00
```

On occasion the sub_total will need to update (products are added for instance), and the total also needs to be updated. I have created a Trigger to update the sub_total. How would I also update the total based on sub_total and shipping?

I have attempted the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_order_product_update AFTER UPDATE ON order_product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `order_total` 
    SET `value` = NEW.`total` WHERE `order_id` = NEW.`order_id` AND `code` = 'sub_total'; 
    UPDATE `order_total` 
    SET `value` = (SELECT `value` FROM `order_total` WHERE `code` = 'shipping' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`) + (SELECT `value` FROM `order_total` WHERE `code` = 'sub_total' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`) WHERE `code` = 'total' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`;
END;
```

Here I receive a "You can't specify target table 'oc_order_total' for update in FROM clause Error No: 1093"

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_order_product_update AFTER UPDATE ON order_product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE SBvalue VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE SHIPvalue VARCHAR(32);

    UPDATE `order_total` SET `value` = NEW.`total` WHERE `order_id` = NEW.`order_id` AND `code` = 'sub_total'; 


    SET SBvalue = (SELECT `value` FROM `order_total` WHERE `code` = 'sub_total' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`);
    SET SHIPvalue = (SELECT `value` FROM `order_total` WHERE `code` = 'shipping' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`);

    UPDATE `oc_order_total` SET `value` = `SBvalue` + `SHIPvalue` WHERE `code` = 'total' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`;
END;
```

Here I receive a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN
UPDATE `order_total` 
SET `value` = (
    (SELECT `value` FROM (
        SELECT `value` FROM `oc_order_total` 
            WHERE `code` = 'sub_total' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`) 
    AS mySubTotalTable 
    WHERE `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`) + 
    (SELECT `value` FROM (
        SELECT `value` FROM `oc_order_total` 
            WHERE `code` = 'shipping' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`) 
    AS myShippingTable 
    WHERE `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`))
WHERE `code` = 'total' AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id`;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SBvalue = (SELECT `value` FROM `order_total` WHERE `code` = 'sub_total'
                AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id` LIMIT 1);
SET SHIPvalue = (SELECT `value` FROM `order_total` WHERE `code` = 'shipping'
               AND `order_id` = NEW.`order_id` LIMIT 1);
```

Give limit 1 for the second query error..

Hope this helps

Comment: If you give it the LIMIT 1, would that not simply return the first row from the result set? Therefore it would only update order_id 1 and not all the other orders?

Comment: You are right , it will return only 1 value...A subquery should return a single value..
so what is SBalue?pls expalin

Comment: Essentially SBvalue = `value` where `code` =  'sub_total' and SHIPvalue = `value` where `code` = 'shipping'. 

Each order_id has a sub_total, shipping, and total. 

When the sub_total is updated, the total also needs to be updated. However, if you use a LIMIT 1, this would only update the first order in the result which would not account for multiple sub_total updates.